# How to create black transparent overlay/ modal dialog with centered text on an image

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a black transparent overlay with centered text on an image on hover. Sort of how Instagram does it hear with each image [here](https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/) (hover over the images)

I have tried doing something like this:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.child p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.child:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="someimageurl">
  <div class="child">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This has failed miserably. Please note that the solution should also work with video tags.

Comment: The proper term is "modal" or "modal dialog"

Comment: @j08691, thanks - edited the question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Give your container a relative position.
2. Assign `display: flex;` `justify-content: center;` `align-items: center;` and `position: absolute;` to your modal.
3. Hide the overlay using `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` and reveal it on hover with `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`. (Using `rgba()` will not assign the opacity to your text, which is why you should use it over opacity) To hide the text, you can use `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible;` to show it.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

img {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.overlay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.container:hover > .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw1MI.jpg"/>
  <div class="overlay">Darth Maul</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet looks good! I'll try it in a few minutes. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, would the .image class be needed then?

Comment: No, you could just select it with `img {}` if you wanted to.

Comment: Hunter - if I might ask a small follow up question. how would you put an <a> tag around this? it hasnt been working for me

Answer (score 1):

Fade-in and slide-down variations you can consider. Run the snippet below.

```css
.child p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: auto;
    top: 45%;
    position: absolute;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: .7s;
}

.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent:hover .child {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: .4;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

.parent:hover .child.slide-down {
    top: 0;
}

.child.slide-down {
    top: -500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
     <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <div class="child">
     <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
     <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <div class="child slide-down">
     <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way to do this would be to have the image "cover" already there, but hidden until mouseover:

```
#parentdiv { background-image:url('myimage.jpg'); }

#parentdiv div { width:100%; height: 100%; opacity:0.2; background: #000; text-align:center; display: none; }
```

with HTML as such

```
<div id="parentdiv">
    <div><!-- text icons in here --></div>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
document.getElementById("parentdiv").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    this.children[0].style.display = 'block';
});
```

and for mousing out:

```
document.getElementById("parentdiv").addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    this.children[0].style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: any way to do this without having the background image in the css? I'm bringing these images dynamically with js